# Convert Java object to JSON with jackson

Tags: shapefile, json

I am trying to read the data from a shapefile and once read, I want to convert it to a JSON file.

To read the data I'm using the geoTools library, and to write to JSON, I use the geojson-jackson library (https://github.com/opendatalab-de/geojson-jackson).

I have managed to correctly read the information data extracted from the shapefile, but I cannot get the JSON file to be well generated.

This is part of my code:

Read Data from .shp

```
public void esShapefileParcel(){

// ShapeFile Directory 
                String archiveshpParcel = directory+"\\"+constant.getTmpParcel()+"\\"+constant.getTmpParcel()+".shp";

                Parcel parcel = new Parcel();

            try {

                File shapeFile = new File (archiveshpParcel);
                FileDataStore store = FileDataStoreFinder.getDataStore(shapeFile);
                SimpleFeatureSource featureSource = store.getFeatureSource();
                SimpleFeatureCollection collection = featureSource.getFeatures();
                SimpleFeature fParcel;

                SimpleFeatureIterator itrParcel = collection.features();

                while(itrParcel.hasNext()){

                   parcels.clear();

                   fParcel = itrParcel.next();
                   parcel.setExternalReference((String)fParcel.getAttribute("REFCAT"));

                   parcels.add(parcel);

                   ObjectMapper Obj = new ObjectMapper();
                   String jsonStr = Obj.writeValueAsString(parcels.toString());
                   System.out.println(jsonStr); 

                }


        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printTrace();
        }

            }
        }
```

And, my Parcel object is:

```
public class Parcel{

    protected String type;
    private String externalReference;

    Parcel(){};

    Parcel(String type, String externalReference) {
        this.type = "parcel";
        this.externalReference = externalReference;
        }


    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public String getExternalReference() {
        return externalReference;
    }

    public void setExternalReference(String externalReference) {
        this.externalReference = externalReference;
    }


    @Override
    public String toString() {

             return "  \"type\" : \"" + type + "\""+
               ", \"externalReference\" : '" + externalReference + '\'' ;   

    }
```

But this, only returns a invalid Json:

> "[  \"type\" : \"null\", \"externalReference\" : '3545013XG2734N']" "[
>   \"type\" : \"null\", \"externalReference\" : '8401550XG1670S']" "[ 
>   \"type\" : \"null\", \"externalReference\" : '8401522XG1680A']" "[ 
>   \"type\" : \"null\", \"externalReference\" : '9293903XG1699C']" "[ 
>   \"type\" : \"null\", \"externalReference\" : '9293907XG1699C']"

Answer (score 2):

Why not use [GeoTools](http://geotools.org) to handle the input and output? Then your code becomes simply something like:

```
File inFile = new File("/home/ian/Data/states/states.shp");
File outFile = new File("/home/ian/Data/states/states.geojson");
if (outFile.exists()) {
  outFile.delete();
}
outFile.createNewFile();
// Read
DataStore inputDataStore = DataStoreFinder.getDataStore(
        Collections.singletonMap("url", URLs.fileToUrl(inFile)));

String inputTypeName = inputDataStore.getTypeNames()[0];
SimpleFeatureType inputType = inputDataStore.getSchema(inputTypeName);

FeatureSource<SimpleFeatureType, SimpleFeature>
        source = inputDataStore.getFeatureSource(inputTypeName);

FeatureCollection<SimpleFeatureType, SimpleFeature>
        inputFeatureCollection = source.getFeatures();

Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>();
params.put(GeoJSONDataStoreFactory.URLP.key, URLs.fileToUrl(outFile));
// Write
DataStore newDataStore = DataStoreFinder.getDataStore(params);

newDataStore.createSchema(inputType);
String typeName = newDataStore.getTypeNames()[0];

SimpleFeatureStore featureStore =
        (SimpleFeatureStore) newDataStore.getFeatureSource(typeName);

featureStore.addFeatures(inputFeatureCollection);
newDataStore.dispose();
inputDataStore.dispose();
```

}

If you don't want to export all the attributes of the shapefile features you need to modify `newDataStore.createSchema(inputType);` to use a new limited schema. This needs something like:

```
SimpleFeatureType outType = DataUtilities.createSubType(inputType, new String[] {"type","REFCAT"});
newDataStore.createSchema(outType);
```

Comment: Thanks for your advice Ian Turton, without a doubt the code is much more efficient in this way.